# Proving that the change of parameters is differentiable.

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification, proof-writing, implicit-function-theorem

Let $M \subset \Bbb R^3$ be a regular surface, and ${\bf p} \in M$. Let ${\bf x} : U \subset \Bbb R^2 \to M$ and $\overline{{\bf x}}:\overline{U} \subset \Bbb R^2 \to M$ be parametrizations at ${\bf p}$. Here $U, \overline{U}$ are open (and $\overline{U}$ has nothing to do with the closure of $U$, it is just notation to guide myself here, the less letters, better). If $W = {\bf x}(U) \cap \overline{{\bf x}}(\overline{U}) \ni {\bf p}$, then ${\bf x}^{-1}\circ \overline{{\bf x}}:\overline{{\bf x}}^{-1}(W) \to {\bf x}^{-1}(W)$ is differentiable.

I want to prove this last assertion. Here's my work:

---

Call ${\bf x}(u,v) = (x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$ and $\overline{{\bf x}}(\overline{u},\overline{v}) = (x(\overline{u},\bar{v}),y(\bar{u},\bar{v}),z(\bar{u},\bar{v}))$. Fix $(\bar{u}_0,\bar{v}_0) \in \overline{{\bf x}}^{-1}(W)$, and write $(u_0,v_0) = {\bf x}^{-1}\circ \overline{{\bf x}}(\bar{u}_0,\bar{v}_0)$.

Since ${\bf x}$ is regular, suppose WLOG that: $$\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}(u_0,v_0) \neq 0.$$
Consider $\varphi: {\bf x}^{-1}(W) \subset \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ given by $\varphi(u,v) = (x(u,v),y(u,v))$. Then: $$\det({\rm d}\varphi_{(u_0,v_0)}) = \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}(u_0,v_0) \neq 0,$$ and by the inverse function theorem, exists $V \subset {\bf x}^{-1}(W)$ open containing $(u_0,v_0)$, such that $\varphi^{-1}: \varphi(V) \to V$ exists and is differentiable. We can write: $$\varphi^{-1}(x,y) = (u(x,y),v(x,y)).$$

Let $\pi: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^2$ be the projection in the first two components. It is differentiable. Hence:

$$\begin{align*} \varphi^{-1} \circ \pi \circ \overline{{\bf x}}(\bar{u},\bar{v}) &= \varphi^{-1}\circ \pi ((x(\overline{u},\bar{v}),y(\bar{u},\bar{v}),z(\bar{u},\bar{v}))) \\ \varphi^{-1} \circ \pi \circ \overline{{\bf x}}(\bar{u},\bar{v}) &= \varphi^{-1} ((x(\overline{u},\bar{v}),y(\bar{u},\bar{v})) \\  \varphi^{-1} \circ \pi \circ \overline{{\bf x}}(\bar{u},\bar{v}) &= (u(x(\overline{u},\bar{v}),y(\bar{u},\bar{v})),v(x(\overline{u},\bar{v}),y(\bar{u},\bar{v}))) \\ \varphi^{-1} \circ \pi \circ \overline{{\bf x}}(\bar{u},\bar{v}) &= {\bf x}^{-1}\circ \overline{\bf x}(\bar{u},\bar{v}) \end{align*} $$

This way, $\varphi^{-1} \circ \pi \circ \overline{{\bf x}}= {\bf x}^{-1}\circ \overline{\bf x}$, and the result follows because the change of parameters is a composition of differentiable functions. So it is differentiable in a neighboorhood of $(\bar{u}_0,\bar{v}_0)$. But even this point was arbitrary.

---

I'm not used to using the inverse and implicit function theorems, so I appreciate **any** feedback you guys have. Please see if there is anything wrong with my proof. This is the main issue. If there is nothing wrong, I also welcome easier, alternative proofs. I know that I can just open some books and go after it, but I think it is more instructive to see comments and remarks from people here (and it might be helpful for anyone reading this, also).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You used the same name for the coordinate functions of both $\bf\bar x$ and $\bf x$, so the rest of the proof is not clear for me. Try to fix it, I will edit this answer after that. :)

Since you speak portuguese, you may take a look at theorem 3.1 at this text: http://www.ime.usp.br/~vinior/texts/geodif.pdf